# Сохранение таблиц dataGridView в файл html

Tags: c#, html

Хочу сохранить таблицу в файл html, не изображением. Подскажите ресурсы или какие-нибудь туториалы по этой теме.

**Обновление**

Массив чисел из textBox, столбиком 24 числа.
В самой таблице я источник не указывал, только таким образом:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(mass_year_2010[n], mass_month[n], mass_mount[n], price_2010, mass_income_10[n]);
}
```

Comment: А что у Вас выступает в качестве источника данных для DataGridView?

Comment: @Korol_tref, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, для начала все же скажу, что так хранить данные не надо. Данные нужно хранить в какой-нибудь коллекции или хотя бы в [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.90).aspx), а для `DataGridView` просто указывать источник данных. Собственно, `TextBox` с числами столбиком также представляется мне плохой идеей. А теперь по делу.

Вы же знаете, как сверстать на `HTML` таблицу, правда? Решение сводится именно к этому. И для удобства я все же буду работать с `DataTable`:

```
var html = new StringBuilder(); // Тут будет наш html
html.AppendLine("<table>"); // Начало таблицы
// Сначала делаем заголовки
html.AppendLine("<tr>"); // Начало строки
foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
{
    html.AppendLine(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", column.ColumnName));
}
html.AppendLine("</tr>"); // Конец строки
// Теперь сами данные
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    html.AppendLine("<tr>"); // Начало строки
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        html.AppendLine(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", row[column]));
    }
    html.AppendLine("</tr>"); // Конец строки
}
html.AppendLine("</table>");
```